# How to reduce oAuth2 application permission to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

**My use case**
I have an application which allows users from different companies to access BigQuery.

As part of the login flow, the users enable access to their bigQuery account using Google oAuth2 standard workflow.

**My problem**
Google oAuth2 provide 1 relevant access level to BigQuery, as can be seen in [oAuth2 playgound](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

[image]

This means that if the user has full access to BigQuery, my application also have full access.

I would like to **avoid** this, so in BigQuery roles terminology, described in this  [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) I want my app to have *dataEditor* permission even if the user has a *dataOwner* permission.

How can this be done **without creating a specific service account** and only using oAuth2 API flow?

Comment: Current answer is: You accomplish this with a service account. Otherwise this is a great feature to request on the BigQuery issue tracker.